# Distributed algorithm for SVD?

Tags: algorithm, linear-algebra, distributed-computing, distributed-system, svd

Is there any distributed algorithm possible for calculating Singular value decomposition of a matrix?
As far as if have explored at many places it is written (like [here](https://www.irisa.fr/sage/bernard/publis/SVD-Chapter06.pdf) pg-132) that because of high communication cost the distributed algorithm is not efficient for Singular value decomposition.
If anyone has some idea about it. Please share some relevant research paper or articles regarding the same.

Comment: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-dimensionality-reduction.html

Comment: @Tom Do they mention that the algorithm works more efficient than sequential one? Even after O(k) passes.